# Profile sync daemon - constant lack of space errors even though there's plenty of space

Tags: linux, firefox, user-profiles

I just recently started using [profile-sync-daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Profile-sync-daemon) on a Debian system to sync my Firefox profile with a tmpfs in RAM in order to speed my system up. It seems to be working fine.  However, when I try to open WhatsApp Web - which I guess was taking up most of the space in my old profile - I keep getting errors saying my computer is "out of space."  This does not make sense, because the old profile was 1.3G in full size, but I now have 2.0G in total in `/run/user/1000`. Why is this happening?

In more detail, here is the relevant output from `psd parse` (to tell me the size of the old profile):

```
 browser/psname:  firefox/firefox
 owner/group id:  user/1000
 sync target:     /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/*******.default-release
 tmpfs dir:       /run/user/1000/user-firefox-*******.default-release
 profile size:    191M
 recovery dirs:   1 <- delete with the c option
  dir path/size:  /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/********.default-release-backup-crashrecovery-20230119_205024 (1.3G)
```

This seems to tell us that the old profile was 1.3G in size?

I have adjusted the `RuntimeDirectorySize` parameter in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to 25%, resulting in this line when I run `df -h`:

```
tmpfs           2.0G  191M  1.8G  10% /run/user/1000
```

So this should be plenty of space.  Do I need even more?

Answer (score 0):

> I have adjusted the RuntimeDirectorySize parameter in /etc/systemd/logind.conf to 25%

This is correct if you want to increase the amount of RAM used by `psd`.

To clarify:

```
$ grep Size /etc/systemd/logind.conf
RuntimeDirectorySize=25%
```

However, the line in the output of `df` is not what you showed, but the ones with overlaid (if using overlaid).

```
$ df -h | grep user
tmpfs     3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs     3.2G  247M  3.0G   8% /run/user/1000
overlaid  3.2G  247M  3.0G   8% /run/user/1000/<username>-waterfox-xxxxx.default
overlaid  3.2G  247M  3.0G   8% /run/user/1000/<username>-google-chrome
```

You may say that they all occupy `/run/user` and I would agree.

> So this should be plenty of space. Do I need even more?

Hard to tell. Depends how many browsers you have using `psd` (I have 2) and how you use them.

Since the limit specified is not RAM reserved but rather max RAM used, I would increase it (I just did from 10% to 25%). Remember to reboot after changing.